# Maclaurin series for $\frac{\sin(\sqrt z)}{\sqrt z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\sqrt z$ and $\frac{\sin \sqrt z}{\sqrt z}$ are well defined and analytic on the cut

$\mathbb{C}-(-\infty, 0]$

Is it correct ? to write

$$  \sin \sqrt z =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}(\sqrt z)^{2k+1} \Rightarrow \frac{\sin \sqrt z}{\sqrt z} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}( z)^{k}  $$

Explain why it's possible to define $f(z)$ on the cut $(-\infty , 0]$ so that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.

What values $f(x)$ should be assigned when $x \in (-\infty , 0]$ ?

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}(-x)^k$

Can this procedure be applied to $g(z)=\sin \sqrt z$ ?
The answer is Yes

Comment: Should't it be $\sqrt{z}^{2k}=z^k$ in the last series?

Comment: Thank you .I 'll correct that mistake